# NoSuchMethodFound for DefaultHttpClient.execute method

Tags: java, maven, http

while running a test to do a Post, I am ending up in the following error.

```
lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;)Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse;
```

did some research and found out:  http://ars-codia.raphaelbauer.com/2014/03/debugging-maven-classpath-problems.html

this is the dependency I have :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Both HttpClient and HttpCore are 4.3.2.

I have played around with the dependency exclusions as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: Where have you set their version? Do you have any other dependencies that depend on `httpcleint` or `httpcore`?

Comment: Fixed it, issue was that the restEasy requires httpClient 4.2.1 and I am using 4.3.2